# Overheating results in system shutdown

Tags: linux, monitoring, cpu, temperature

I have been having an overheating issue which makes my laptop shutdown immediately. Is there anyway to monitor the temperature from the sensor and scale down the CPU frequency to avoid that problem? Is there any existing software or shell script that can handle that job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at `cpufreq-set` and `cpufreq-info`. On Debian and derived distros they are in the `cpufrequtils` package. For example, on an old laptop with a bad fan that I use as a file server at home I have made these settings:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -g ondemand -u 800000
sudo cpufreq-set -c 1 -g ondemand -u 800000
```

Comment: Great, I've just tried and it work great!

Comment: Also `cpupower frequency-info` `cpupower frequency-set -u -u 1200000`. But this does **not** guarantee that temp will go down. For my old core 2 duo CPU setting max speed from 2GHz to 1.2GHz doesn't show any measurable change in power consumption (checked on power outlet).

Answer (score 5):

There are such tools, but you should look into blowing dust out of your laptop cooler heatsink instead.  If that doesn't help you might want to examine/replace thermal grease under heatsink or ultimately bring your laptop to authorized service.

Note: disassembling a typical laptop might be not a trivial task, but instructions can be found on the web rather easily.  Consult your warranty card before disassembling!

Comment: I has disassemble already to clean vacuum from air vent and also use an external cooler but it don't help much. I'm living in a big city so the way to clean vacuum frequently will make my laptop go damage fast :P may the better heatsink can help a bit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cpupower-gui` for Ubuntu.